# material text field label not copyable?

Tags: material-ui

I am using MUI's Text Field component and found there's literally no way to copy the label contents. Is there a way to copy the label somehow?

See the demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/4ou0l7?file=/demo.tsx

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because material UI is disabling the label selection using CSS.

You can enable it back in a few ways. You can enable it for a certain field or across all of them using the material UI theme override ability.

In order to ***enable label selection only to one field***, you have pass an additional prop to your `TextField`: `InputLabelProps={{ sx: { userSelect: "text" } }}`

And here I have provided you with the second way to ***do that for all the text fields***:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiInputLabel: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          userSelect: "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

const StateTextFields = () => {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState("Cat in the Hat");
  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setName(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Box
      component="form"
      sx={{
        "& > :not(style)": { m: 1, width: "25ch" }
      }}
      noValidate
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      <TextField
        id="outlined-name"
        label="Name"
        value={name}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <TextField
        id="outlined-uncontrolled"
        label="Uncontrolled"
        defaultValue="foo"
      />
    </Box>
  );
};

export default () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <StateTextFields />
  </ThemeProvider>
);
```

Of course, you can extract this `ThemeProvider` into a separate file and wrap with it the whole project, not only this file. It is combined just for the example.

Comment: do you mind taking a look at this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73480207/inputlabelprops-inside-autocomplete-is-not-honored

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that this can be done using the `helperText` and my solution is  more of a hack. I am using the `helperText` and positioning it where the label was used to be, giving it a background and bringing it to front using `z-index`.
Also you can either choose to use the `label` or replace it with the placeholder depending if you are happy with the animation.

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-violet-yhx7c6?file=/demo.tsx:504-900) based on your code in case you need it.

```
<TextField
    id="outlined-name"
    label="Name"
    // placeholder="Name"
    value={name}
    onChange={handleChange}
    helperText="Name"
    sx={{
      "& .MuiFormHelperText-root": {
        top: "-11px",
        position: "absolute",
        zIndex: "1",
        background: "white",
        padding: "0 4px",
      }
    }}
  />
```